# how to make soft brush

Tags: c#, graphics, line, brush, blurry

please does anyone know how to make soft brush like this in C sharp (Windows forms)? I couldnt make it work using Texture or gradient brushes, I need to use it for freeline panting. So the user will draw with this soft stroke.

http://www.jennifersmith.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/hardsoft.png

https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS7oP85-FsDAH12WrMtL4EVn_4kC1IlAgApVTKRFJgrttbdqox-Tg

Thank you so much

Comment: I have already googled a lot, trust me...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I just made bitmap for the blurred brush and I am rendering them along drown line. It's working pretty well now.